# Side by Side column merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I need to create a price comparison tool so such requirement came. For this, I have two different results sets from my database query. My database is SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition. What I want is a side by side merging of two result sets. See the image below:

[image]

My query

```
SELECT ADuration Duration, APlan_Price AmazonPrice 
FROM tbl_AmazonPlans
WHERE AProduct_Name = 'Air Conditioner'
  AND 14678 BETWEEN TRY_CONVERT(int, PARSENAME(REPLACE(APrice_Range, '-', '.'), 2))
                AND TRY_CONVERT(int, PARSENAME(REPLACE(APrice_Range, '-', '.'), 1))

SELECT Duration, Plan_Price GwPrice
FROM tbl_PlanDetails
WHERE Product_Name = 'Air Conditioner'
  AND 14678 BETWEEN TRY_CONVERT(int, PARSENAME(REPLACE(Price_Range, '-', '.'), 2))
                AND TRY_CONVERT(int, PARSENAME(REPLACE(Price_Range, '-', '.'), 1))
```

### update

Result sets coming from tables may/may not have same schema. Also there's no point of joins as they donot have common keys. But yes they contains few columns that might be same and based on those same columns i have to obtain the expected resultset.

Comment: And do you assume that both tables contain the same set of values for Duration? For example, what should appear in your resultset when one table contains rows with value 10 but the other does not?

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text.

Comment: @DaleK - As far as I know, screenshots are far easier and better than formatted texts for explaining the issues/results. Also, if its not a community standards by SO Team then this(embedding image) have had been removed by the SO developers itself.

Comment: No, screenshots are not easier or better... they are heard to read, don't work as well on mobile devices and generally interrupt the flow of the question. Images should only be used when trying to show a User Interface or a Report Layout. And in fact sample data is best presented using DDL+DML because then people can copy and paste it out to work on solving your question. [Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: [Further reference](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could join the tables directly, but in case your `where` criteria can be different to keep it simple you can just join the result sets directly

```
select a.duration, a.AmazonPrice, b.GwPrice
from (
    Select ADuration Duration, APlan_Price AmazonPrice 
    From tbl_AmazonPlans
    Where AProduct_Name ='Air Conditioner'
    and 14678 between try_convert(int,parsename(replace(APrice_Range,'-','.'),2))
                                and try_convert(int,parsename(replace(APrice_Range,'-','.'),1))
)a
join
(
    Select Duration, Plan_Price GwPrice
     From tbl_PlanDetails
     Where Product_Name ='Air Conditioner'
    and 14678 between try_convert(int,parsename(replace(Price_Range,'-','.'),2))
                                and try_convert(int,parsename(replace(Price_Range,'-','.'),1))
)b on a.duration = b.duration
```

Comment: I'd do a FULL OUTER JOIN, to also include products available in only one of the stores.

Comment: It looked like the rows in each table match, but sure agreed, if the OP can have inconsistent data in either then a full join would be appropriate; it may also be the case the `PlanDetails` table might only have a subset of rows, in which case it may be better to have a `left join`. The OP will know his data, i'm sure.

Comment: @Stu Please see my update. Yes the table schemas aint similar but yes  few columns like the two can be found in each table. Also there's no  possibilities of joins betwwen these tables..

Answer (score 0):

Is the Duration column a identifier common in the two tables? If it is, then you can use inner join.

```
select
    Duration,
    APlan_Price as AmazonPrice
    Plan_Price as GwPrice
from tbl_AmazonPlans
inner join tbl_PlanDetails on tbl_PlanDetails.Duration = tbl_AmazonPlans.Duration
where /* Your filter here */
```

Comment: You left out the conversion/comparison of column tbl_AmazonPlans.APrice_Range. You should be using this to teach good coding habits - like using a statement terminator, defining table aliases, and then using those aliases for every column reference.

Comment: I agree with you SMor but in this case the question was specific about how to return the two columns side by side. The user dosn't need use alias for tables. This is optional. About the where filter, i think there are other best options to filter data but I think this is no relevant at this moment. I will edit my answere removing the where clause from the example.